# Bash on Windows: script only progresses in -v mode

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell

I have a script which starts like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "Running on OSTYPE: '$OSTYPE'"
DISTRO=""
CODENAME=""
SUDO=$(command -v sudo 2>/dev/null)

echo foo
```

When I run it as-is or with `bash -x`, it stops after the assignment to SUDO, I get as only output

```bash
+ DISTRO=
+ CODENAME=
++ command -v sudo
+ SUDO=
```

When I add -v to the bash invocation to get even more verbose output, the script runs normally and I see my "foo". I'm using bash 4.4.23 as shipped on https://git-scm.com/downloads

What is going wrong on my system and how can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `$(command ...)` is a subshell.

Instead of `set -x` or `bash -x` create a file like follow inside **your home folder**:

**.bash_env**

```bash
set -x
```

So the `set -x` will be applied to any new **bash** instance and subinstance.